# How to use rendered Zend View in JSON Object

Tags: json, zend-framework, zend-view

I'm trying to use a rendered view in a JSON object and then
return this to the client. How can I render a phtml file that doesn't really
belong to specific action?

The requested action from the client has no view.
It then calls prepareForm(). Inside this function i want to render
form.phtml and pass the output to the 'html' key of the array.

```
private function prepareForm()
    {
        $json = Zend_Json::encode(array(
            'html' => $this->partial('form.phtml'),
            'role' => $this->role,
            'lang' => $this->lang
        ));

        echo $json;
    }
```

How can I do this in the Zend Framework? What's the best way to do this?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an Zend View instance:

```
private function prepareForm()
{
    $view = new Zend_View();
    $path = '/../'; // Replace with path to phtml

    $view->addScriptPath($path);

    $json = Zend_Json::encode(array(
        'html' => $view->render('form.phtml'),
        'role' => $this->role,
        'lang' => $this->lang
    ));

    echo $json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the layout and view using in your action:

```
$this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

To me, `echo` from controllers is not the right way to do things. The MVC pattern is used to separate logic to view. You can just disable the layout and assign to your view the json to render as follow:

```
$this->view->json = $json;
```

and in your view:

```
<?= $this->json ?>
```

If your request comes from an Ajax script, you can even makes things prettier using the `AjaxContext` action helper. This will allow you to use one action for different kind of request for example, and render the right view according to the request type (Ajax, etc).